# Nested Views with Dynamic Id's Angular & Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, controllers

Hey I have Angular rendering a list of Quotes as resources. The Quotes are stored in a rails back end. I am at the point where I would like to use Angular to render the show.html for that specific quote resource.

I havent been able to get angular to resolve to the state.
I'm not sure if I understand how to pass id's into state. 
I need help figuring out how to get angular to render the show.html in the ui-view labeled "fullquote" for the specific quote. Here is my code.

**Quotes.html**

```
<div class="quotes col-xs-10 col-md-8" ng-controller="QuotesCtrl" >
    <div ng-repeat="quote in quotes">
      <a ng-click="showQuote(quote);">
        <span ng-if="quote.read == false"> *NEW*</span>
        <span>Quote id: {{quote.id}}</span>
        <span>Name: {{quote.name}}</span>
        <span>Email: {{quote.email}}</span>
        <span>City: {{quote.city}}</span>
        <span>Region: {{quote.region}}</span>
        <span>State: {{quote.state}}</span>
      </a>
      <div ng-show="quote.visible">
        <a ui-sref="quotes/{{quote.id}}"> View </a>
        <ui-view="fullquote"></ui-view="fullquote">
        <a ng-click="quotes.splice($index, 1)"> Delete </a>
        <div ng-if"">
          <span>  {{quote.question2 }}</span>
          <span>  {{quote.question3 }}</span>
          <span>  {{quote.question4 }}</span>
          <span>  {{quote.question5 }}</span>
          <span>  {{quote.question6 }}</span>
          <span>  {{quote.question7 }}</span>
          <span>  {{quote.question8 }}</span>
          <span>  {{quote.question9 }}</span>
          <span>  {{quote.question10 }}</span>
          <span>  {{quote.question11 }}</span>
          <span>  {{quote.question12 }}</span>
          <span>  {{quote.question13}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Quotes.js**

```
app.factory('Quotes', ['$resource',function($resource){
 return $resource('/quotes.json', {},{
 query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
 create: { method: 'POST' }
 })
}]);

app.factory('Quote', ['$resource', function($resource){
 return $resource('/quotes/:id.json', {}, {
 show: { method: 'GET' },
 update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'} },
 delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'} }
 });
}]);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', { url: '', templateUrl: 'static_pages/home.html'})
    .state('quotes', { url: '/quotes', abstract: false, views : { templateUrl: 'quotes.html', controller:   'QuotesCtrl'}})
    .state('quotes/:id',  { url: 'quotes/:id', view: { "fullquote": { templateUrl: 'show.html', controller:   'QuotesCtrl'}}})
    .state('quotes/:id.pdf', { url: 'quotes/:id.pdf', controller:   'QuotesCtrl'})
    .state('users', { url: '/users', templateUrl: 'users.html', controller:   'UsersCtrl'})
    .state('/users/:id', { url: 'users_show.html', controller: "UsersCtrl" });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise( function($injector, $location) {
        var $state = $injector.get("$state");
            $state.go("home");
    })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });
});

app.controller("QuotesCtrl", ['$scope', '$state', '$http', 'Quotes', 'Quote', '$location',  function($scope, $state, $http, Quotes, Quote, $location ) {
    $scope.quotes = Quotes.query();
    $scope.quote = Quote.query();

    $scope.showQuote = function (quote) {
        quote.visible = !quote.visible;
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Can you tell me what JSON data does a quote contain when you request it from the server?

Comment: your state naming is wrong as well

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you should look into:

1. Your state naming is incorrect. I assume you are trying to use nested states.In this case you need to have `quotes.detail` or something of the kind.  Also, in the state,  you need to name your object `views` instead of `view`. Please, refer to [UI.Router multiple views guide](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) for more information.

   .state('quotes.detail', 
        { url: 'quotes/:id', 
          views: { 
         "fullquote": { templateUrl: 'show.html', 
                        controller:   'QuoteCtrl'}
         }
        })
2. To pass a parameter to the state you need to change your link to this. If you'd like to know more about passing parameters to ui.router states - read the [manual](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing):

`<a ui-sref="quotes.detail({{quote.id}})"> View </a>`

3. If you want to have a separate view, you also need to have separate controller for it. I named it it `QuoteController`. You can get ht `:id` from the URL by injecting `$stateParams` in the controller. More info about getting parameters into the controllers - [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing):

   `//QuoteController
   ['$stateParams, Quote , function($stateParams, Quote) {
     Quoute.get({id:$stateParams.id});
   }]`

I'm not sure this will completely solve your problem, but it will certainly bring you closer to solving it. I hope I was helpful!

Comment: This helps. It clears some confusion. I've done nested views without dynamic :id's but now passing the id's is confusing. I'm able to get into the state quote.detail but I still do get the quote.id in the url or if I don't set a url I dont get the state to render the template url.

Comment: You need a separate controller and $stateParams to get the parameter from the URL. I updated my answer